# VBA xlCount function

Tags: vba, excel

Hey I'm learning VBA programming for Excel, I'm looking at others peoples code learning what each function does and then modify it and see the outputs (I find this the easiest way to learn new subjects).

I have come across a function

```
Function:=xlCount
```

But I can't seem to find any information about it when I google I might be looking in the wrong place. Can someone explain what the xlCount is doing or point me in the direction of a site that lists VBA functions that I can learn from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*xlCount* is not a function.

This is just a member of the **XlConsolidationFunction enum** which is used for controlling pivot tables generation.